# Can an Indian citizen traveling in the US on a tourist visa apply for an Australian visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, australia

My parents are currently in the US on a tourist visa. Now they would like to visit Australia on their way back to India. They are both Indian citizens.

Can they apply for Australian tourist visa from within the US? If so, what do they need to do in order to apply?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but the document list for a visitor visa (600), as a tourist is [comprehensive](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Tourist-Stream-document-checklist). They cannot apply online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Get them to contact [the Americas Service Centre](http://usa.embassy.gov.au/whwh/About_DIACwashington.html), which they'll have to do anyway to initiate the process in the US, and the staff will either walk them through the process or say that they can't process them in the US.**

Indian citizens need to get [the Visitor Visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-) to enter Australia as a tourist, as they're not included for [Electronic Travel Authority](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/601-) or [eVisitor](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-) visas.  [They're also unable to apply for the Visitor Visa online](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-/Visitor-e600-visa-online-applications).

[The requirements to produce for an Australian visa](http://india.embassy.gov.au/files/ndli/Checklist%20-%20600%20Tourist%20Stream%20-%20ND%20Post%20version%20-%20Sep%2015.pdf) include:

- Notarised copy of all pages of current passport.
- Two recent passport-sized photographs.
- Details of tourism-related bookings, and itinerary giving details of activities within Australia.
- Copies of financial documents indicating a consistent savings history, any assets, and taxation documents for three years.
- Letter from employer indicating job status and confirmation of approval of leave, or (if retired) evidence of retirement.
- Other health and character documents if required.

This first three are probably doable while on the road.  The last three are probably going to be more difficult and may make it impossible for your parents to apply from overseas.

If all of these documents are able to be compiled while overseas, to apply for a visa while in the USA [they will then need to contact the Americas Service Centre](http://usa.embassy.gov.au/whwh/About_DIACwashington.html) which (presumably) walks them through the process including getting the required documents to the local consulate.

Comment: As mentioned by you too, last 3 documents will not be possible for them to collect while in U.S, so they have to go back to India and then apply for the visa.